# Slow Paypal IPN by 3 seconds

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I have a paypal IPN system in place.  The payment system works very well, it takes t he required amount of money fine, however the IPN is just **slightly** off.

I've done some timestamps on the time the IPN connects to my site and the time I load the /shop/thanks page - and here is the data:

**IPN:**
`[1416406186 // 14:09:46 19-11-14] papypal.php runtime: 1 seconds. (start time: 1416406185 / end time: 1416406186)`

**/shop/thanks error:**
`[1416406183 // 14:09:43 19-11-14] /shop/thanks error - could not display thank you message.`

**THREE SECONDS**.  If I go straight through the paypal process I get to my website 3 seconds before paypal updates me via IPN.  If I go through it slowly then most likely I get correct `thank you` page.

I haven't encountered this problem before.  What can I do to sort it out?  The runtime of the paypal.php script is 1 second, so It's not like I am taking too long to update the database.

Comment: You need to switch to a different API method. IPN is meant for reporting and back-office management. Try using an [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/#ec) method instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. IPN is supposed to be asynchronous. You are supposed to say "thank you for your payment, we will notify you when your payment is complete."

But why?

Because let's say I decide to pay you by eCheque, ie. directly from my bank account through PayPal. eCheques may take *six to ten **DAYS*** to clear.

IPN may stand for "Instant Payment Notification", but the "Instant" part refers to when you actually *get* the payment, not when the user *sends* it to you.

Now, that being said, you *might* be able to adjust your IPN script to accept "Pending" status payments, and act accordingly. However, this is not necessarily a good idea because it may mislead the user into thinking their payment has completed, when in fact it may be cancelled or deemed invalid later. But that's a question for UX. Even then, you'd still have some kind of delay while the IPN system processes your notification.

Comment: Golly.  I have IPN functional on other websites, and it doesnt seem to be slow there.  I will test it though.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Chud37 One thing to notice is that PayPal will usually have a "Taking you back to X" page once payment is done, which will wait for about 10 seconds before redirecting you - this is meant to allow most IPN cases to process before sending the user back. Of course, this isn't a guarantee that IPN will work in that time, and in any case there's a manual link the user can click to go back without waiting, but it usually helps.